# View Push Notifications from other app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

is there any way in xcoce where i can program my app to see the system-wide notifications. So, for example if i am writing an app which will display all the push notificatiosn in the system?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do that, that would get you past Apple's review team (iOS 7).